# scrollbar in table with percentage in the table columns

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to add a horizontal scrollbar to my table. But, unfortunately, don't know how to progress with this. Here is the [link](https://jsfiddle.net/2ctq8nbw/29/) that I have tried. So, what I am trying to achieve is that to have a `min-width: 500px` to the table where the scrollbar will appear. Also, note that the, first column should take the 30% of the space where the second column will take the 70% of the space. Any ideas on how to solve this? There should be a scrollbar from left to right when the table react to it's `min-width: 500px.`

Here is the example of the code:

```css
table {
  max-width: 1000px;
  min-width: 500px;
  overflow-x: auto;
  border: 1px solid;
}

.first {
  width: 30%;
  border: 1px solid;
}

.second {
  width: 70%;
  border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="first">Title one</td>
        <th class="second">Title two</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="first">Content one</td>
      <td class="second">Content two</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Please put relevant code direct into the question. See  https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example and please explain more about the scrollbar. I'm not understanding why or where it is needed.

Comment: Edited the question and put the code there. What I am trying to do is that, a horizontal scrollbar in the table if the table size goes below 500px.

Comment: NOTE: I made a snippet of the HTML you posted but it is malformed and I did NOT fix that.

Answer (score 0):

Solution with a `div` wrapper tag:

The wrapper `<div class="wrap">` takes 100% of available width, but its child `table` can only be from 500px to 1000px wide. When there is less than 500px of available width the wrapper is shown with a horizontal scrollbar, since it cannot contain the table fully which is still 500px wide.

```css
.wrap {
  overflow-x: auto;
}

table {
  max-width: 1000px;
  min-width: 500px;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid;
}

.first {
  width: 30%;
  border: 1px solid;
}

.second {
  width: 70%;
  border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th class="first">Title one</th>
        <th class="second">Title two</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td class="first">Content one</td>
        <td class="second">Content two</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

To see how it works run the code snippet, click "Full page" and change a browser window width to:

- less than 500px
- more than 500px
- more than 1000px

Comment: Perhaps elaborate on the what/why you feel this works rather than just "Try this:"

Comment: Would "Solution with a wrapper tag:" be enough?

Comment: No, that's not enough. Note that @MarkSchultheiss asked for an elaboration on ***why*** you feel this works, not just what it is. Also, the Stack Snippet editor has a Tidy button/link on it; use it so that the indentation of code is consistent.

Comment: Also note that I see no scroll bar and you might explain why or when/condition that would show one since that is what the OP asked about.

Comment: Thanks, how about now?